# Ayuda, me sale el error -mysqli

Tags: mysqli

Me gustaría saber porque tengo error en la variable `$sql`, el único error que tengo es el de:

> "Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, bool given
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema\nuevousu2.php on line 20"

de antemano gracias por su ayuda

saludos

```
<?php 
$host='localhost';
$user='user';
$password='******';
$db='*******';
$conn= @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db);
if(!$conn){
    echo "Error";
}

$id=$_POST['id'];
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$area=$_POST['area'];
$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$contra=$_POST['contra'];
$rol=$_POST['rol'];
$contraadmin=$_POST['contraadmin'];
$sql="INSERT into login(id,Nombre,Area,Usuario,Contra,Rol) values ('$id','$nombre','$area','$usuario','$contra','$contraadmin')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
      $mensaje = "Orden Registrada Correctamente";
      echo "<script>";
      echo "alert('$mensaje');";  
      echo "window.location = '';";
      echo "</script>"; 
} else {


}

 ?>
```

Comment: quita el `@` en `mysqli_connect` y dime que pasa después

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema\nuevousu2.php on line 19, el error sigue estando en el ig con el mysqli_query y ya tambien le quite el arroba pero sigue el error

Comment: Si `$conn` es de tipo `boolean` es debido a que la conexión con la base de datos falló. Considera utilizar `echo mysqli_connect_error();` en seguida de la conexión `mysqli_connect()` y verás que tienes un mensaje de error esperándote. Probablemente debido a uno de los parámetros que le envías

Answer (score -2, accepted):

fijate en tu tabla si la columna rol es de algún tipo de dato diferente a lo que te llega en contraadmin, ya que en tu consulta SQL estas insertando eso en vez de la variable $rol

Comment: El mensaje que nos muestra Luis indica que la conexión falló, por lo tanto, no se procesó la sentencia SQL

Comment: Muchas gracias, el problema no era en si ese pero si eran el manejo de los tipos de datos agregados con los establecidos en la tabla

Comment: @LuisGarza si el problema no era este, porque aceptaste esta respuesta? la respuesta aceptada deberia por lo menos solucionar el problema. Puede poner tu propia respuesta de ser asi.

Comment: Porque el problema estaba en un tipo de variable en la tabla

Answer (score -2):

la instruccion `mysqli_query` requiere

- como primer parametro la `sql`,
- como segundo la `conexion`.

[mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: Gracias por comentar pero ese no es el problema porque el código lo tengo igual en las demás querys que hago y todo esta bien, igual ya probé el cambio y me sale el mismo error, comoquiera gracias por tu tiempo amigo

Comment: parece que te esta dando error en el mysqli_connect. lo tienes anulado con el @, por lo que la asignacion puede ser un booleano u otra cosa. Puedes probar con un print_r($conn) despues del mysqli_connect, para ver que te esta dando. De todas formas, mysqli_query te pide la sql primero y luego la conexion, y lo tienes puesto al reves. Revisa eso (los otros sitios de tu codigo puede que tenga mysql_connect, sin la i) que requiere los parametros al reves, ademas que esta deprecated)

Comment: Lo probe de nuevo amigo y aun nada, ya cambie los parametros de nuevo en el mysqli_connect sin y con el arroba y nada, lo raro es que toda mi app esta tal cual el codigo original de arriba y funciona perfectamente, nadamas este archivo me da el error

Comment: Tu publicación es incorrecta, [según la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), el primer parámetro que debes enviar es la conexión, y de segundo parámetro la sentencia SQL.